# Ошибка в запросе INSERT INTO php

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь выполнить такой запрос:

```
 $rs = mysql_query("INSERT INTO street1 (user_id) VALUES('$user['id']')");
```

В итоге, из-за $user['id'] возникает ошибка. 
Если вывести $user['id'] через echo - значение будет определено. Как я понимаю, подставлять значение в таком виде запрещено?

Comment: спасибо большое. разобрался)

Comment: @splash58 самое смешное что это не поможет, посольку ты сам путаешься в кавычках еще больше

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том что ты пихаешь переменную прямо в запрос. А надо всегда передавать переменные **отдельно**

Чтобы правильно добавить данные в БД, надо

1. Написать запрос, в котором все переменные заменить на знаки вопроса
2. Подготовить запрос к выполнению
3. Привязать переменные к запросу
4. Выполнить

В итоге получаем такой код:

```
<?php
// подключаем соединение
require_once 'mysqli.php';

// создаем запрос SQL в котором все переменные заменены на знак вопроса
$sql = "INSERT INTO street1  (user_id) VALUES (?)";
// подготоваливаем запрос
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql); 
// привязываем переменные к запросу
// указывая тип для каждой переменной. для простоты всегда можно использовать тип "s"
$stmt->bind_param("s", $user['id']);
// выполняем запроc
$stmt->execute();
```

при таком способе у нас **никогда не будет ошибок синтаксиса**, не говоря уже об sql инъекциях.

Comment: Я использую mysql, a не mysqli.

Comment: такого модуля в РНР нет. то есть используя какую-то дремучую версию пхп, ты тупо стреляешь себе в ногу, поскольку твой код нигде не будет работать

Comment: всегда так делал, однако, с $user['id'] по неизвестной мне причине возникла ошибка. пришлось создать переменную $user_id = $user['id']

Comment: ошибка возникла потому что язык надо учить, чтобы им пользоваться, а не тупо копипастить куски кода

Comment: своего рода практика)

Comment: @Ипатьев Вот с одной стороны Вы правы - mysqli есть везде и он всем лучше, чем древний mysql. С другой стороны - зло начинается не тогда, когда человек начинает копаться в древностях, а когда он тащит эту древность в прод на хоть сколько-то серьёзный проект. В археологии самой по себе нет ничего плохого. Иногда полезно посмотреть как кодили раньше) Тем более ещё вполне может встретиться legacy code с дремучей версией PHP. Так что зря Вы так категоричны. Впрочем, за Ваш ответ я всё равно проголосовал.

Answer (score 0):

используйте фигурные скобки

```
 $rs = mysql_query("INSERT INTO street1 (user_id) VALUES('{$user['id']}')");
```

или уберите одинарные кавычки  в массиве

```
 $rs = mysql_query("INSERT INTO street1 (user_id) VALUES('$user[id]')");
```

если вам принципиально, то можно так

```
 $rs = mysql_query("INSERT INTO street1 (user_id) VALUES('".$user['id']."')");
```